# Permissions problem in Docker container built in Ubuntu VM composed of files created on Windows host

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I work on a project that has a large number of Java SpringBoot services (and other types) running in k8s clusters.  Each service has a small start script that executes a more complex script that is provided in a configmap.  This all works fine in builds and at runtime.

I need to make some changes to that complex script.  I've already made the changes and tested the concept in an isolated script.  I still need to do more testing of it.  I am attempting to take some of the command lines that run in our Linux build system and run them on my VirtualBox Ubuntu VM that runs on my Windows 10 laptop.  Although I am running this on the VM, most of the files were created and written on the host Windows 10 laptop that I get to using a VirtualBox Shared Folder.

When I look at the "ls -l" output of "startService.sh", I just get this:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    634 Aug 24 15:07 startService.sh*
```

Note that I am running docker with my own uid, and I have that uid in the "vboxsf" group.

It seems like when the file gets copied into the image, either the owner or the perms get changed in a way that make it inaccessible from within the container.

I tried adding a "RUN chmod 777 startService.sh" in the Dockerfile, just before the ENTRYPOINT, but that fails at build time with this:

```
Step 23/26 : RUN chmod 777 startService.sh
 ---> Running in 6dbb89c930c1
chmod: startService.sh: Operation not permitted
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod 777 startService.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I don't know why this is happening, or whether this is something that might mitigate this.

My "docker build" command looks like it went fine. I saw it execute all the steps that the normal build shows.  The "docker run" step seemed to go fine, but it finished very quickly.  When I looked at the "docker log" for the container, it just said entirely:

```
/bin/sh: ./startService.sh: Permission denied
```

Note that everything here is done the same way it is on the build server.  There seems to be something funny with the fact that I'm running an Ubuntu

Comment: I have basically resolved this.  I don't have any information about what VIrtualBox is doing to permissions of files from shared folders, but accepting that it does what it does, I've worked around the problem with a "USER root" and a "RUN chown ...". I wouldn't release it this way, but that wasn't the point of this work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `chmod +x startService.sh` before `docker run` or `docker-compose up -d --build`

And example Dockerfile for django. Look at actions with wait-for, you must make same

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-slim as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc \
    python3-dev musl-dev libffi-dev\
    && pip install psycopg2

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . .

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . .

#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-slim

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup --system app && adduser --system --group app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/static
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/media
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/currencies
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev bash netcat rabbitmq-server
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
COPY wait-for /bin/wait-for
COPY /log /var/log
COPY /run /var/run

RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME
RUN chown -R app:app /var/log/
RUN chown -R app:app /var/run/

EXPOSE 3000

# change to the app user
USER app

# only for dgango
CMD ["gunicorn", "Config.asgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers", "3", "-k","uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker","--log-file","-"]
```

Comment: If you reread my post, you'll see that I showed the "ls -lt" output of the file I'm copying into the image.  It is already rwx for user and group.

Comment: Are you coppy your sh in bin, when use your Dockerfile?